# Compile a C program using HTTP request

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, gcc

I want to make an website for students who want to learn programming (just a personal project). For backend, I use Spring Boot and React for frontend. I created a service function which enables me to compile some code and test it over multiple tests from the database:

```
 private static void pseudoWait(File file, boolean condition) {
        while(true) {
            if (condition) {
                if (file.exists()) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public int getScore(String code, Long problemID) throws IOException {
        List<ProblemTest> problemTests = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ProblemTest> allTests = (List<ProblemTest>)problemTestRepo.findAll();
        for (ProblemTest test : allTests) {
            if(Objects.equals(test.getProblem().getId(), problemID)) {
                problemTests.add(test);
            }
        }

        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("code.c");
        myWriter.write(code);
        myWriter.close();

        ProcessBuilder compileProcess = new ProcessBuilder("gcc", "code.c", "-o", "output");

        compileProcess.start();
        File file = new File("output.exe");
        pseudoWait(file, true);
        
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ProblemTest problemTest : problemTests) {
            myWriter = new FileWriter("test.in", false);
            myWriter.write(problemTest.getInput());
            myWriter.close();

            File outputFile = new File("test.out");
            var ignore = outputFile.delete();
            pseudoWait(outputFile, false);

            compileProcess.command("output.exe");
            compileProcess.start();
            pseudoWait(outputFile, true);

            results.add(Files.readString(Path.of("test.out")));
        }


        file = new File("test.in");
        file.delete();

        file = new File("test.out");
        file.delete();

        file = new File("code.c");
        file.delete();



        List<String> correctOutput = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ProblemTest problemTest : problemTests) {
            correctOutput.add(problemTest.getOutput());
        }

        int correctTests = 0, ct = 0;
        int totalTests = problemTests.size();


        for(int i = 0; i < totalTests; i ++) {
            if(correctOutput.get(i).equals(results.get(i))) {
                correctTests ++;
            }
        }

        double score = ((double) correctTests / totalTests) * 100;
        System.out.println(score);
        return (int)score;
        return 0;
    }
```

The controller is:

```
@PostMapping("/evaluate/{problemID}")
    public ResponseEntity checkSolution(@PathVariable Long problemID, @RequestBody String code) throws IOException {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(service.getScore(code, problemID));
    }
```

It works fine when I tested from Postman, but it's not ok from the browser. I noticed that it can't compile the file using gcc. I am also open to sugestions about how can I do this in a more efficient / simple way.

The request is done, but it stops at gcc. I really don't know what to do.